# [dji-sdk][onboard-sdk] Loosing GPS while in Onboard control flight mode

Tags: dji-sdk

How does the DJI UAV (A3 or M600) behave if the GPS signal was completely lost during the flight and the setpoint was given as Horizontal command in ground_ENU frame.

According to this [appendix](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/appendix/index.html):

- Only when the GPS signal is good (health_flag >=3)，horizontal position control (HORI_POS) related control modes can be used.
- Only when GPS signal is good (health_flag >=3)，or when Guidance system is working properly with Autopilot，horizontal velocity control（HORI_VEL）related control modes can be used.

Will the DJI switch to Attitude Flight mode? 
Will you still have the authority to control over Onboard-SDK? And if yes, does this mean that you could control it only via **HORI_ATTI_TILT_ANG** mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I never test the full case which hook up the dji a3 and osdk and let it crash.

What I tested is using ground set up with A3 and turn off the ESC and motor. Run the mission and plot the GPS. But I moutned many other sensors to get the correct position/velocity command.

When next to the building. GPS went to crash on the building. The DJI GPS mission control follows that. The GPS from DJI sdk is denoted in the green line. I have to use aullixary visual and Lidar based navigation to get to correct position

[image]